# Fetching Popular Movie Data and Translating with Riverpod | TMDB API

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, clean-architecture

In my project, I need to fetch popular movie data from the TheMovieDB API and also translate the movie's name
and overview to Brazilian Portuguese using their Translation API.

I've run into some issues with my current implementation.

**I'm not sure how to make it so that I can display the translated movie name and overview, while also being able to display the originals should I need.**

Here's a brief overview of my current implementation:

- I have a `PopularMovie` class to represent movie data.
- I use Riverpod to manage the state and fetch popular movies.
- I also have a `MovieTranslation` class to represent translation data.

Here are the code samples for the classes:

**PopularMovie**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import '../utils/genre_helper.dart';

class PopularMovie {

   int id;
   String originalTitle;
   String overview;
   double score;
   String posterPath;
   String releaseDate;
   List<int> genreIds;
   //MovieTranslation translations;

  PopularMovie({required this.id,
      required this.originalTitle,
      required this.overview,
      required this.score,
      required this.posterPath,
      required this.releaseDate,
      required this.genreIds,
      //required this.translations
  });

   List<String> getGenreNames(List<int> genreIds) {
      return GenreHelper.getGenreNames(genreIds);
   }

  factory PopularMovie.fromJson(String str) => PopularMovie.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  factory PopularMovie.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    final List<int> genreIds = List<int>.from(json['genre_ids'] ?? []);

    return PopularMovie(
      id: json["id"],
      originalTitle: json["original_title"],
      overview: json["overview"],
      score: json["vote_average"]!= null ? json["vote_average"].toDouble() : 0.0,
      posterPath: json["poster_path"] ?? "",
      releaseDate: json["release_date"] != null ? json["release_date"].toString() : "",
      genreIds: genreIds,
      //translations: brTranslation
    );
  }
}
```

**MovieTranslation**

```
import 'dart:convert';

class MovieTranslation {

  final String iso_3166_1;
  final String translatedName;
  final String translatedOverview;

  MovieTranslation({
    required this.iso_3166_1,
    required this.translatedName,
    required this.translatedOverview
  });

  factory MovieTranslation.fromJson(String str) => MovieTranslation.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  factory MovieTranslation.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MovieTranslation(
        iso_3166_1: json["iso_3166_1"],
        translatedName: json["data"]["title"],
        translatedOverview: json["data"]["overview"]
    );
  }
}
```

**MovieApiRepository**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:traux_tmdb/data/movie_repository.dart';
import 'package:traux_tmdb/models/movie_translation.dart';
import 'package:traux_tmdb/models/popular_movie.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../utils/constants.dart';

class MovieApiRepository implements MovieRepository {

  final String _popularMovieUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=$apiKey';

  @override
  Future<List<PopularMovie>> fetchPopularMovies() async {

      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(_popularMovieUrl));

      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
        final List<PopularMovie> popularMovies = (jsonData['results'] as List)
        .map((data) => PopularMovie.fromMap(data))
        .toList();

        return popularMovies;
      } else{
        throw Exception("Erro ao buscar filmes populares");
      }
  }

  @override
  Future<MovieTranslation> fetchTranslations(int movieId) async {

    final String translationsUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/$movieId/translations?api_key=$apiKey';

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(translationsUrl));

    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonData = json.decode(response.body);

      final translationData = (jsonData['translations'].firstWhere(
          (translation) => translation['iso_3166_1'] == 'BR',
        orElse: () => null
      ));

      return MovieTranslation.fromMap(translationData);
    } else{
      throw Exception("Erro ao buscar tradução do filme");
    }
  }
}
```

**MovieProvider**

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import '../models/popular_movie.dart';
import 'movie_repository_provider.dart';

final getPopularMoviesUseCaseProvider = FutureProvider<List<PopularMovie>>((ref) async {
  final repository = ref.read(movieRepositoryProvider);
  return repository.fetchPopularMovies();
});
```

And this is my `HomeScreen`, ideally, I would like to change `title: Text(movie.originalTitle),` to something like `title: Text(movie.translations.translatedName),`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import '../providers/popular_movie_provider.dart';

class Home extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final popularMovies = ref.watch(getPopularMoviesUseCaseProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body:popularMovies.when(data: (movies) => Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                for(final movie in movies)
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(movie.originalTitle),
                  )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
          , loading: () => const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
          error: (err, stack) => Text("Error: $err")
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

I just need some guidance on how to do it, I'm somewhat new to programming and I'm trying to apply some clean code concepts while using Riverpod.